# Does it make any difference if I will have some text after # tag for SEO

Tags: seo

I am making my url like this `/project/show/1`. As you can see `1` is ID.

Will it make any difference if I will add project name after hash tag like this `/project/show/1#New Project` or it won't make any difference for seo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have in mind that Search engine spiders take into account the complexity of the url - the simplest the better, as it is supposed to be user friendly. That is why MVC 3 (.NET) for example is by default SEO friendly (or at least it is much easier to make it compared to classic ASP.NET).

Comment: Well, yea. However if in MVC3 you will have `/user/32` vs. `/user/natalia` will it make any difference?

Comment: Meaningful words > numbers :). Generally search engines will search for key words in your url; natalia, beer, etc. are well known words and therefore they can be considered as keywords, while 32 can be anything but for sure is not a keyword (unless you are searching for a 32 bit OS, but that is very specific and almost certainly is not related to Natalia with ID=32).

Answer (score 0):

Search engine spiders generally [ignore hash fragments](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html).